# How to launch a transparent activity so that background activity is able to take events

Tags: android

Is it possible in android that one transparent activity is on the top and a background activity is able to handle the events?

If yes then please refer the below image 
[image]

As in image i have one activity in background with button click and another activity with drawer. And i want that button in the background activity can able to handle events.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. But why would you want it?

Comment: I am agree with Peter, IT's  not possible

Comment: I am also thinking in the same way but is their any out of box solution exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to make this work with the following code in my transparent foreground activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Pass touch events to the background activity
        getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
...
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: I thank you for reading API docs and sharing. You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

I have never tried, but creating a [**`SlidingDrawer`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) with a Fragment inside should work.

Using the Compatibility library will work till android 1.6!

```
 <SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

<fragment android:name="your.package.name.yourFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </SlidingDrawer>
```

On your button, you will add:

> public void animateOpen ()
>
> Since: API Level 3 Opens the drawer with an animation.

Comment: Ya thanks for your response i got your point but my question actually that the sliding drawer is not included in same activity it itself in the other activity with translucent theme.and till the drawer is not open is it possible that background activity can take events

Comment: As you can see in your question comment, working with 2 separate activities is NOT POSSIBLE. If you work with fragment, that are totally similar to activities, that will work and is in my mind the only proper way to achieve what you want.

Comment: OK that is what i want to know.Thanks for your response.